# Do until empty row loop in macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a data file with one column and several rows (dynamic list). I want to transpose the first 28 rows to the first row, the second 28 rows to the second row and so on. I want this to run till an empty row is found. However when i run the code it only transposes the first 28 rows. I have not been able to get results with the "do until empty" loop and am unable to spot the error.
Thanks for your help.

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    '
    Range("A1").Select
    Do
    Range("A1:A28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please don't post images of code when you can just paste the code directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro recorder won't do the loop for you. You do need to pull the `Offset` out of the loop. Otherwise, fully qualify it:

**UPDATE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()

Dim CopySheet As Worksheet
Dim PasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set CopySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set PasteSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set MyRange = CopySheet.Range("A1:A28")
r = MyRange.Rows.Count
i = 1

Do Until wf.CountA(MyRange) = 0
    MyRange.Copy
    PasteSheet.Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Set MyRange = MyRange.Offset(r, 0)
    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @DirkReichel Wrong, no. Incomplete, yes. I asked him to put his code in the question. Looks like Tim Williams did, too.

Comment: @DirkReichel Yes, I understand. I appreciate that. Hopefully, you'll like my improvement. I still consider myself intermediate. So I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Yes... looks much better now ;)

Comment: The file looks like this (https://s17.postimg.org/dixy4iaxr/image.png), I also need to, apart from the first column, delete the rest of the columns containing the timestamps.

Comment: @yezdi You should probably create a separate post for that.